# PHP Objects and their Functions

Tags: php, type-safety

I am using PHP 5 now and I am exuberant to use OOP in PHP 5. I encounter a problem. I got few classes and few functions inside them. Few functions require arguments to be passed which are object of those classes I wrote myself. Arguments aren't strictly typed I noticed. Is there a way to make it strictly typed so that at compile time I could use Intellisense?

Example:

```
class Test
{
   public $IsTested;

   public function Testify($test)
   {
      //I can access like $test->$IsTested but this is what not IDE getting it
      //I would love to type $test-> only and IDE will list me available options including $IsTested
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) to do what you want:

```
public function Testify(Test $test) {

}
```

Either that, or the docblock:

```
/**
 * @param Test $test The test to run
 */
```

It depends on the IDE, and how it picks up the type hints...  I know that NetBeans is smart enough to pick up the type-hint `Testify(Test $test)` and let you go from there, but some other IDEs are not that smart...  So it really depends on your IDE which answer will get you the autocompletion...

Comment: OK I need to give this a try and will let you know

Answer (score 1):

I was going to give a simple "No." answer, then found the section on [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) in the PHP docs.

I guess that answers that.

```
<?php
class Test
{
   public $IsTested;

   public function Testify(Test $test)
   {
      // Testify can now only be called with an object of type Test
   }
}
```

I'm not sure Intellisense knows about type hinting, though. That all depends.

Comment: OK I need to give this a try and will let you know

Answer (score 1):

`$test` isn't class variable.
Maybe you want `$this`?

```
$this->IsTested;
```

OR

```
public function Testify(Test $test)
{
   $test->IsTested;
}
```

Comment: He's referring to `$test`, the argument of `Testify`.